# ASP NET CORE 2.0 localized views

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-localization

I have an asp net core 2.0 app. There's some views with static data that i have to translate according to culture. I'm going to create multiple views like someview-en.chtml, someview-fr.chtml etc. Is it possible to return view according to request language without creating custom route methods?
I tried to use viewlocalizer, but it requires resource files that i don't want to use.

Answer (score 1):

To have different view files for different cultures, you just need to follow `<View>.<Culture>.cshtml` naming convention, for example:

- `SomeView.en.chtml`
- `SomeView.fr.chtml`

Comment: It seems the post answers your question. Let me know if you have any problem in applying the solution.